# Google Chrome hardware acceleration/css scale causes faulty compositing

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, animation

**The background:**

I am making a 2D HTML/CSS animation using JQuery. This will place roughly 25 same-sized images on top of each other, moving some as desired. UI elements get a pixel position and are much smaller than the full-sized images. I have recently moved from forcing hardware acceleration form backface-visibility: hidden to will-change css properties. The entire animation is scaled by the div it is contained in and the css transform property.

**The problem:**

In Google Chrome specifically, the compositing starts malfunctioning in certain scenes, in a reproduceable but seemingly random manner. Images are partly cut off, images are placed behind images they are supposed to be on top of, the like. Scrolling up and down replaces some malfunctions with others, as does changing the display properties of some items (happens due to UI interaction).

**The question:**

What is causing this behaviour, why are all my other test browsers (firefox, opera, internet explorer, edge) not affected, and how can I avoid it?

**My current status:**

From what I have tried so far and my gut feeling this is an issue caused by overuse of hardware acceleration or the transform: scale css property, or a combination of both. I'm currently working on other scaling methods as the easiest "fix" to the problem, but I still do not know what is causing all of this. Sadly all of my UI elements aren't a neat % of the parent.

**What I tried:**

1. Firstly I tried setting the z-index for all elements manually. This accomplished nothing, sadly.
2. As sometimes scrolling up/down or interacting with the UI seemed to fix problems, I tried adding a method that would force the browser to re-do the layout at certain points in code. This argueably only made things worse, as it added a lot of white flickering, and failed to fix the issue.
3. I tried switching animation libraries from jquery to velocity, which did not help.
4. I removed the "hack" that forced things into hardware acceleration. This fixed the compositing problem, but reintroduced choppy animations in chrome (only).
5. I then tried to assign hardware acceleration on a need-to-get basis by adding and removing a css class containing the "hack". The behaviour was the same as in 4 .
6. I tried using will-change instead of the backface visibility hack, but this just set the behaviour back to where it was before I started my attempts at fixing this.
7. I tried reducing the amount of layers while keeping hardware acceleration. I used jquerys ".hide()" on elements only animating once replaced the final picture with a singular image. This did not fix the issue of composite "mashup".
8. Finally, I disabled the css transform scale property, which fixed the unexpected behaviour, but is imperative so I can scale my animation for screen size.

**Some code:**

Here's some css code of the animation container

```
.animationContainer {
    position: relative;
    width:2560px;
    height:1440px;
    /*transform: scale(0.55);*/
    transform-origin: top left;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And some javascript detailing the animation I use for the majority of objects, making them "fall" into the scene

```
function fadein(el, direct)
{
    var falldistance = 150;
    $(el).show();
    $(el).css("opacity", 0.0);
    switch(direct) {

    case 0: 
    $(el).css("top", "-="+falldistance);
    $(el).animate(
    {
        top: "+="+falldistance,
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 1000);
    break;
[...]
```

I do not know how useful more code would be, if you require any more please ask. Web design isn't a field I have much experience in, and I am slowly running out of ideas. **Any** help or suggestions would be appreciated.

**Example Visual:**

This is an example of one of the bugs:
[image: Bug 1 initial]

This is what it looks like after scrolling down and back up in the browser:
[image: Bug 2 after scroll]

Comment: I added a few pictures to show the kind of unpredictable yet reproduceable behaviour in hopes of getting some input after all. Hope this helps the people looking at this!

Comment: Try to make a [mcve]. Remove everything that is superfluous but still allows to reproduce the issue. At the end, you should have probably just 2 or three divs and a less than 15 css rules. From there we will be able to start investigating, and maybe help you find a workaround. Also, since this is a chrome bug, consider opening an issue on their [bug tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/).